# Ringtone from url

Tags: java, android, ringtone

I have this code :

```
    RingtoneDetails ringtone_240 = new RingtoneDetails();
>>> ringtone_240.setRingtoneid(R.raw.sound); <<<
    ringtone_240.setTitle(RINGTONE_TITLE_240);
    details.add(ringtone_240);
```

to recover a sound from the raw folder of a project.

I would like, instead of loading from the raw folder, to load sound from a URL to save space.

Comment: Where do you want to load the ringtone from, so where should the URL point to?

Comment: to a web type http://www.xxxx.com/sound.mp3

Comment: But what will your app do then if there is no internet connection? Shouldn't the sound always be available?

Comment: The problem is that it has more than 200 sounds and I wanted to try with sounds from the server. which you recommend to save that space?

Comment: You could offer the user an option to download the ringtones they want from your server, so you have only the ringtones saved locally that are really needed.

Comment: Good idea Thank you very much!